# Lists nested inside dictionary

Tags: python, file, dictionary, defaultdict

So I'm trying to develop a way to way to store 4 different categories (lets call them A, B, C, D) inside a dictionary so that I can access the keys/values inside each dictionary and check them against a file name. So far, I've been able to store 3 of these categories inside the dictionary but not the 4th. The categories were from an excel file and then copied over to a regular .txt file (I've included the .txt file). Is there a way to add a 4th component to my dictionary?

Link .txt file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2s43FKt5BZgQldULXVOR0RBeTg/view?usp=sharing

Here's my script:

```
from collections import defaultdict
source_file = <file path>-<file name>.txt
data_set = defaultdict(list)    #sets up a defaultdict because there may be multiple overlapping keys
s = [b for b in [i.strip('\n').split('\t') for i in open(source_file)] if b]  # removes new line & tab spaces in .txt file
for a, b, c, d in s: # a is donor, b is barcode, c is batch, d is donor
  if a == 'Component1':  # We don't want to save the column headings
    pass
  else:
    data_set[a].append({b: c})  # creates the default dictionary
```

the output is like this as of the moment:

```
{'1':[{'ab':'tg'},{'dd':'dd'}],'2':{'dc':'yh'},3:{'we':'hh'}}
```

Comment: use the `csv`-module for tab-separated files.

Comment: Your input file has two lines with a `Component1` value of `1`. What do you want to happen when this occurs? What **should** the dictionary look like (don't really care what your current code outputs)?

Answer (score 1):

You can store your columns as tuples:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict
source_file = "<file path>-<file name>.txt"
data_set = defaultdict(list)
with open(source_file) as f:
    lines = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
    _ = next(lines) # skip header
    for donor, barcode, batch, donor2 in lines:
        data_set[a].append((barcode, batch, donor2))  # save columns as tuple
```

Comment: How easy is it to access the values inside the tuples? Also, what if there's multiple data for a single donor? Would there be 2 tuples for a particular dictionary key then?

Comment: Tuple items can be accessed by index and for multiple entries per donor you have the lists of defaultdict.